# How to draw a circular, inclined road in 3D?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, tikz-3dplot, pst-solides3d

I want to draw the road which is similar to the following (but please ignore grass, soil, and the surrounding scenery for the sake of simplicity),

[image]

to illustrate a physics problem about circular motion. I have not tasted the power of `pst-solides3d` because of its lengthy documentation. My attempt is as follows but it looks not so good in 2D.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[dimen=m](-5,0)(5,4)
    \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray]{\pspolygon(-5,0)(-5,1)(-1,0)\scale{-1 1}\pspolygon(-5,0)(-5,1)(-1,0)}
    \bgroup
        \psset{linecolor=lightgray}
        \psline(0,4)(0,3.5)
        \psline(0,3.25)
        \psellipticarc{->}(0,3.5)(1,.25){-90}{270}
    \egroup
    \pcline[linestyle=none](-5,1)(-1,0)\naput[nrot=:U,npos=.25,labelsep=-.5\pslinewidth]{\rput(.5,.5){\small car}\psframe(0,.25)(1,.75)\psline[linewidth=3pt](.25,0)(.25,.25)\psline[linewidth=3pt](.75,0)(.75,.25)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to draw the complete circuit first and move the viewport such that it looks like the first image above. I believe your answer will help me to learn the rest easily.

Comment: The road is not a really a inclined circle, but part of a surface. Perhaps parts of a paraboloid will better fit your purposes.

Comment: I understand about circular motion, but from a mathematical point of view: The form of the road can not be circular. However, a solution depends rather on the 'accuracy' and art of graphic rendering.

Comment: @ChristianH.  If one wanted the "mathematical" solution to the road shape, the slope of the road (measured towards the center of curvature) is such that the component of weight parallel with the road surface (M g sin alpha) exactly balances the centripetal force (M V^2/R) when the car is travelling at the road's design speed.  When designed properly, the car should neither slide to the inside nor outside, even on a slippery road.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Yes, I know about centripetal force also ;-) All I was writing was to state the form of road is not circular at all since it is a surface with curvature, not just a curve.

Comment: @ChristianH. And I was writing merely to point out that a paraboloid would not mathematically suffice, except under perhaps extremely restricted conditions (e.g., step jump from zero to maximum road curvature).

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: I agree with that.

Comment: @steven how I wish it was that simple :) my msc diploma would be 1 year earlier hehe. the cars cannot turn without sliding but I know what you mean. It is just my bad memories :D

Comment: @percusse  Well, of COURSE I'm assuming the spherical automobile!  Didn't I make that clear? ;^)

Answer (score 5):

Well, here's a start.  Using Jeff Hein's (quite brilliant) `tikz-plot3d` (suggested by your tag), I have built at least the outer and inner bounds of a racetrack (in magenta).  All other elements you wish to include, as well as the viewing angle, may be implemented with this package (I think), and would probably provide a great familiarisation course in the package.

As a first step, I recommend playing around with the values in `\tdplotsetmaincoords{80}{110}` and observing the different viewing angles...

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{80}{110}
%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rvec}{.8}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\thetavec}{30}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\phivec}{60}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords]
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
    \tdplotsetcoord{P}{\rvec}{\thetavec}{\phivec}
    \draw[-stealth, color=red] (O) -- (P);
    \draw[dashed, color=red] (O) -- (Pxy);
    \draw[dashed, color=red] (P) -- (Pxy);
    \tdplotdrawarc{(O)}{0.2}{0}{\phivec}{anchor=north}{$\phi$}
    \tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\phivec}
    \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{0.5}{0}%
        {\thetavec}{anchor=south west}{$\theta$}
    \draw[dashed,tdplot_rotated_coords] (\rvec,0,0) arc (0:90:\rvec);
    \draw[dashed] (\rvec,0,0) arc (0:90:\rvec);
    \draw[thick, color=magenta] (\rvec/2,0,0) arc (0:180:\rvec/2); % inner edge of racetrack
    \draw[thick, color=magenta] (\rvec,0,0.3) arc (0:180:\rvec); % outer edge of racetrack
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Offset Concentric Curves]

Comment: What did you do folks?